# Coroutine inside ViewHolder? [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewholder

I'm wondering if it's possible launch a `Coroutine` inside `ViewHolder`, I mean, Imagine that you press an item inside `OnBindViewHolder` and you need to call an `API` to get a response... I don't know if I could use `Coroutines` inside it!

Thank you so much

PS. Or Something like this

```
lblDeliveryMethod.setOnClickListener {
           // API CALL
            APICALLING()
            suspend {
                delay(1000)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    if (APIRESPONSES) {
                        // DO SOMETHING
                   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix it using this plugin... it works like a charm

https://github.com/satoshun/CoroutineAutoDispose

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
  holder.itemView.autoDisposeScope.launch {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Why cant we just use CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
} inside a ViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this, this is plain wrong. Perform background work inside the components that are designed for it, like the ViewModel, which has a Lifecycle that survives configuration changes and has a CoroutineScope that is tied to the ViewModel's Lifecycle.

Your ViewHolder should provide a way for the Fragment/Activity that hosts the RecyclerView to register an onClickListener, and call a method on the ViewModel when it is clicked.

You can either take a lambda as a constructor parameter on your list item, or have a setOnClickListener() method on the list item, and a property to store it.

Comment: Sorry for not providing code, since I don't have any similar code laying around as I always use the FastAdapter library which implements it for me.